# C# EventHandler with parameters changing its value

Tags: c#, event-handling

I have a table which keeps growing its size as the user inputs them, and each row has a 'X' Label to remove them as well.

table.RowCount is always up-to-date and so I have a function ~like following that is executed everytime I create a new row:

```
private void storeValues(){
    Label removeLabel = new Label(); 
    removeLabel.Text = "✗";
    removLabel.Click += new EventHandler((s, e) => removeLabel_Click(s, e, table.RowCount));
}
```

The thing is that all removeLabel's **always call the click event with the same parameter value** which is the table.RowCount **NOT the one I created them with but the value is currently having**, so I'm always getting the last row deleted.

```
private void removeLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, int index){
    removeFromTable(index);
}
```

How can I save a fixed value to each removeLabel?

Comment: Have you tried storing `table.RowCount` in a local variable and using that local variable in the lambda expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; that is what *happens* with lexical closures. The only thing you are actually capturing here is the implicit `this` - the value of the expression `this.table.RowCount` is evaluated at the time the delegate is invoked, *every* time the delegate is invoked.

If you want to capture a snapshot: ***capture a snapshot***

```
var count = table.RowCount;
removLabel.Click += new EventHandler((s, e) => removeLabel_Click(s, e, count));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
removeLabel.Tag = table.RowCount;
```

then get the Tag value in the event handler